# I have heard that we can validate incoming data from a source using stored procedures. can so one explain this in a broader way?

Tags: stored-procedures

How to validate incoming data using stored procedures in real time? can some one explain this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but I think this is a bad idea. Business logic does not belong in a database. It belongs in service code (middle tier of an application). The role of a database is to retrieve and save data, not validate it. At least not in the sense of applying business rules.

Now, you can do 'validation' in the database in the sense of check constraints and foreign key validation, but this would not be done in stored procedures. This is native support built into most modern database systems.

So, in my opinion, forget about doing data validation in a stored procedure. As I said, validation doesn't belong there, and, it's going to be much slower than putting that logic in a middle tier using C++, C# etc.